# Loading custom js file on the admin page through plugin

Tags: plugin-development, javascript

I'm new to the world of `Wordpress` and I just started developing my first `plugin`. 
When it's activated it should load one javascript file to `wp-admin/post-new.php` (Add new post) page.

Here is how I tried to do this:

**Plugin**

```
class WP_Blog_Customizer{
    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'load_dependencies') ); 
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'wpa_install' ) );
        register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'wpa_uninstall' ) );
    }
    public function load_dependencies(){
        wp_enqueue_script('blog-customizer', plugins_url('js/blog-customizer.js', __FILE__),array('jquery'),'1.0.0', true);
    }
}
new WP_Blog_Customizer();
```

**wp-admin/post-new.php**

```
if(is_plugin_active( 'blog-customizer/blog-customizer.php' )){
        $plugin = new WP_Blog_Customizer();
}
```

Shouldn't this `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'load_dependencies') );` from the `__construct` of my plugin class include this js file?

**Note**

This js file is located under the js folder in my plugin's folder, so the path is correct.

Can anyone tell me why this is not working, and how to make it work?

Comment: I think you just have to change your hook ! `admin_enqueue_scripts` for admin instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`

Comment: Great job, thanks a lot! :) Paste it as a question, and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have to change your hook ! `admin_enqueue_scripts` for admin instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts` :)